# could not resolve <local:Item> to a component implementation

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to implement item rendere example from TourdeFlex application. However, when I tried to run the application its giving me " could not resolve  to a component implementation" error message beside the local items. I also added the assets folder and verified the visualization.swc.

Please let me know the solution to fix the issue.

THanks in advance.

Serenity.

Comment: Do you have a component named either Item.as or Item.mxml in your src dir?

Comment: no, i don't suck kind of component

Comment: I apologize for the typo. No, I don't have such kind of component in my application.

Answer (score 1):

**local** is XML namespace declared at the top of example, its like `import` in ActionScript. "Could not resolve" means referenced class is not found. Look at that namespace to determine where it must be placed. For example, xmlns:gui="gui.*" declares namespace gui which references classes from folder "gui".

Edit: xmlns:local="*" means "import all files from src directory". In src should be file Item.mxml or Item.as and it is missing (or failed to compile).

Comment: <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
xmlns:local="*" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">

Comment: It's been declared as above and I am unable  to replace the word local.